# How to rotate a node from a custom pivot

Tags: maya

On Maya python api 2.0 I am trying to rotate a node from a custom pivot.

[This is how it looks like inside Maya](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0V9y.gif)

And this is my code:

```
import maya.OpenMaya as om
import maya.cmds as cmds

object_position = om.MVector(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
pivot_pos = om.MVector(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
twist_axis = om.MVector(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
twist_value = 1

transform = om.MTransformationMatrix()
transform.setTranslation(object_position, om.MSpace.kWorld)
transform.setRotatePivot(
    om.MPoint(pivot_pos),
    om.MSpace.kWorld,
    True)

rotation_quat = om.MQuaternion(twist_value, twist_axis) 
transform.rotateBy(rotation_quat, om.MSpace.kTransform)
final_pos = transform.translation(om.MSpace.kTransform)

cmds.spaceLocator(p=(final_pos.x, final_pos.y, final_pos.z))
```

Doesn't seem to rotate from the provided pivot,
What am I missing?

I may add that I've tried with rotatePivotTranslate with no luck either.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I may add that I've tried with rotatePivotTranslate with no luck either.

Comment: If you need to add information, [edit] your question where it can be seen. The edit link is in the lower left corner of your question, below the tags.

Comment: Sorry, I've added my edit now.

Answer (score 0):

A `MTransformationMatrix` is analogous to a transform node in Maya -- the rotation and translation values are independent, applying a rotation will not change the value of the translation component.

What's easier is to fall back on plain matrix math:

1. Make your `MTransformationMatrix`, set it's translation to the pivot point you want.
2. Get the relative position of the point you want to "rotate" by multiplying that point against the `.asMatrixInverse()` of the `MTransformationMatrix`
3. Now apply your rotation.
4. Then multiply the relative position from step 2 against the `.asMatrix()` of your `MTransformationMatrix`.  The result is the new world space position you want.

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om
import maya.cmds as cmds

# from the question code...
object_position = om.MVector(0,1,0)
pivot_pos = om.MVector(0,0,0)
twist_axis = om.MVector(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
twist_value = 1

# note that we set the translation to the _pivot pos_
transform = om.MTransformationMatrix()
transform.setTranslation(pivot_pos, om.MSpace.kWorld)

# get the relative position to the desired point
relative_pos = object_position * transform.asMatrixInverse()

# original rotation code remains the same
rotation_quat = om.MQuaternion(twist_value, twist_axis)
transform.rotateBy(rotation_quat, om.MSpace.kTransform)

# instead of checking the translation, 
# multiply the test point by the transform matrix
final_pos =  relative_pos * transform.asMatrix(1)

# Your locator pos will be rotated around the pivot you supplied
cmds.spaceLocator(p=(final_pos.x, final_pos.y, final_pos.z))
```